# Как дописать к url окончание .xml

Tags: .htaccess

Как подставить в `http://[сайт]/sitemap` расширение `.xml`, чтобы получить `http://[сайт]/sitemap.xml`?

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitemap$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/sitemap.xml
```

Если sitemap был для примера, а надо добавить .xml к любому url, то так

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1.xml
```

Comment: Нужно именно sitemap.xml. http://[сайт]/sitemap.xml не заработал.
"Not Found
The requested URL /sitemap.xml was not found on this server."

Comment: Ну если нету sitemap.xml на сайте - то я чем помогу :)

Comment: Извините, возможно я не правильно описал ТЗ. Есть карта, доступна по http://[сайт]/sitemap. Нужно доклеить через htaccess .xml, чтобы также карта была доступна и по http://[сайт]/sitemap.xml.

Comment: Так вам наоборот надо!
Чтобы при обращении на sitemap.xml перекидывало на sitemap.

      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitemap.xml$
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/sitemap

Comment: Не совсем, мне нужно чтоб именно существовала страница http://[сайт]/sitemap.xml, а не был редирект с /sitemap.xml на /sitemap

Comment: Ну так создайте её в виде link.(ссылки) на саму sitemap.
ln -s sitemap sitemap.xml

Comment: А может тогда проще сделать, чтобы при таком запросе вызывалась карта? Но запрос почему-то тоже не работает.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap.xml
RewriteRule .* /index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1

Comment: Не работает как именно?